# how to replace hyphen with blank space / white space? php

Tags: php

i don't know much about PHP but these days I'm modifying an existing script. I want to know how can I replace - with white or blank space

For example a variable contains 'Love-you' and I want to replace this hyphen between them with  a space like this 'Love you'.

I'll appreciate your feed back.

Answer (score 21):

```
$str = str_replace("-", " ", "Love-you");
```

now `$str` is "Love you";

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `explode` and `implode`

Here is an example

```
$string = "Love-You";
$arr = explode("-",$string);
$string = implode(" ",$arr);
```

Comment: This wouldn't be something I'd recommend, it's likely to use much more memory and be slower than just using str_replace().

Comment: Wow. I know that premature optimization is a bad thing, but you don't need to go this far in the other direction.

Comment: Guys, this is just an alternative, because you have already provided a better answer

Comment: Starx although DrColossos's tweak worked for me but I still appreciate for reading question and trying to help me. 

Guys keep this up. I really liked this forum.